# How to execute js code again whenever a class name change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry for my editting format in advance cos it's been a long time since I asked a question. I will try my best to follow all the rules.

So I have this list which works like an image carousel:

```
<div class="carousel">
  <ul>
    <li class="past"><img src="img1.png"/></li>
    <li class="past"><img src="img2.png"/></li>
    <li class="current"><img src="img3.png"/></li>
    <li class="future"><img src="img4.png"/></li>
    <li class="future"><img src="img5.png"/></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Whenever I click on an image, the clicked item's class name will change to "current" and I will translateX `<ul>` to make "current" `<li>` look "centered". All of these are in "carousel" `<div>`.

However I have another div which has a background of an empty-screen iPhone mockup:

```
<div class = "iphone_screen">
  <div>
    <img class="display" src="blank_screen.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I want to do this to the "iPhone" `<div>`:

```
var imgUrl = $("body").find(".current").find('img').attr('src');
$(".display").attr('src',imgUrl);
```

But this jQuery will only be executed once when I load the page.

So how do I execute my jQuery code again whenever I lick one of the  `<li>` items and make the class name `current` change?

Update: Thank you all for the replies! I feel so stupid......I don't know why I ask this question.........I added a click function before and it didn't work.Then I started to look for alternatives. Now when I think about it, the selector must be wrong.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Why you need to wait for the class name change? You said on click on the slider image, the class changes. So within that click function you can run the code. var imgUrl = $("body").find(".current").find('img').attr('src');
$(".display").attr('src',imgUrl);

Comment: I feel so stupid...please see update..thank you for the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the event that drives everything comes from a click on the `li` you could  run on a click for any `li`'s (inside a `ul`) inside the carousel classed `div`.

```
$(".carousel > ul > li").click(function () {
  var imgUrl = $("body").find(".current").find('img').attr('src');
  $(".display").attr('src',imgUrl);
});
```

Comment: Thank you ! I don't know why I ask this question.........I added a click function before and it didn't work. The selector must be wrong

Comment: Np, I do that more than I'd like to admit. Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

put your code in a function.

```
$(".carousel li").on("click" ,function () {
  var imgUrl = $("body").find(".current").find('img').attr('src');
  $(".display").attr('src',imgUrl);
});
```

Comment: I feel so stupid...please see the update..thank you for the reply